# How does it work : WSManCredSSP server/client role

Tags: powershell-2.0

I want to administrate the company computers with Powershell from my laptop.
So I assume my laptop is the Server and the rest are Clients.
So I make my computer a server (the computer that I initiate all the remote connections)
`Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server`
+ I enter wsman/* in the GPO (which is needed on the machine that initiate the remote)

And then I make the rest of the computers clients as fallows:
`Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer *`

If everything goes as I suppouse I shold be able to connect from the Server to the Client , but I get an error.
But if I try the opposite, from the client to the server it works perfectly (after I set the wsman/* in the GPO of course ).

Can someone explain how Server/Client role are suppose to work ?.

P.S.
The error I get when trying to connect from Server > Client is the fallowing:

`Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process
 the request. CredSSP authentication is currently disabled in the client configuration. Change the client configuration
 and try the request again. CredSSP authentication must also be enabled in the server configuration. Also, Group Policy
 must be edited to allow credential delegation to the target computer. Use gpedit.msc and look at the following policy:
 Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Credentials Delegation -> Allow Delegating Fresh Crede
ntials.  Verify that it is enabled and configured with an SPN appropriate for the target computer. For example, for a t
arget computer name "myserver.domain.com", the SPN can be one of the following: WSMAN/myserver.domain.com or WSMAN/*.do
main.com For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:16
+ Enter-PSSession <<<<  -ComputerName 192.168.30.122 -Credential IT -Authentication CredSSP
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (192.168.30.122:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set your policy to allow delegation of Fresh Credentials?

```
Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System ->
Credentials Delegation -> Allow Delegating Fresh Credentials.
```

What is your Enter-PSSession invocation?

```
PS> $cred = Get-Credential
PS> Enter-PSSession 192.168.30.122 -Authentication CredSSP -Credential $cred
[xxxx.yyyy.local]: PS C:\Users\zzzz\Documents>
```

Comment: Your target computer should give you this: `[TARGETPC]: PS C:\Users\zzz\Documents> Get-WSManCredSSP
The machine is not configured to allow delegating fresh credentials.
This computer is configured to receive credentials from a remote client computer.` I think you have client/server setup backwards.

Comment: Yes, I have setup the policy correctly + adding  wsman/* in both settings. 
Get-WSManCredSSP on the server role machine :
The machine is not configured to allow delegating fresh credentials.
This computer is configured to receive credentials from a remote client computer.
Get-WSManCredSSP on the client role machine :
The machine is configured to allow delegating fresh credentials to the fallowing target(s): wsman/*;wsman/*
This computer is not configured to receive credentials from a remote client computer.

Comment: So in a fact as you said client/server are backwords which I do not get because. I setup client like that :
 Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer *

I do not set  Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server    - on a client computer

Comment: Your initial post says that your are connecting from "Server" to "Client". Which for any meaning of those two words, won't work. You are in fact trying to remote from your laptop (Client) to one of the company's Windows boxes (Server), right? Is your client computer joined to the (same) domain?

Comment: We do not have a domain yet, we are in a workgroup. But I want to have full access to any user laptop in the company from my laptop. When you put it that way, it makes sense to me, BUT! The thing that confised me were the -Delegatecomputer option. 
Is there a way to do the CredSSP authentication without making each user laptop a Server role?